# Can anyone Find the error below

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If: $$S=1+2+4+8+....+2^n +...$$ So we get $$2S=2+4+8+...$$ $$2S+1=1+2+4+8+16...$$ $$2S+1=S$$ $$2S-S=-1$$ $$S=-1$$

Is there error, and if there's, why? I want athletic explanation.

Comment: $S\notin \Bbb R$ that's the problem...

Comment: The series doesn't converge. Don't play with $\infty$

Comment: @Surb , Can you give me you're explanation?

Comment: Jeez, can't anyone search the site before posting this for the $(1+2+4+\cdots)$th time?

Comment: But most importantly: what's an athletic explanation?

Comment: $S$ is not a real number! You can't add, subtract and multiply arbitrary things and expect them to act like real numbers.

Comment: So, you are concluding $2\times \infty+1=\infty\implies \infty = -1$?  Interesting.

Comment: In other words, this is a another illustration of why treating $\infty$ as a real number leads to contradictions.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Now that was unboundedly, "series-ly" hilarious!

Comment: @Ant That is a good one!

Comment: @Ant: An athletic explanation supports the conclusion.

Comment: @AndréNicolas as opposed to an explanation that gives the right answer? Never heard of this idiom before :)

Comment: @ant   I never heard the idiom before either, but Andre was referring to American usage for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jockstrap

Answer (score 3):

Here is your athletic explanation, as requested. Your series are divergent in the real numbers and have no meaning.

On the other hand, the thing is convergent in the $2$-adic numbers $\mathbb Q_2,$ and the sum really is $-1.$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

This is problem 21 on page 20 of Gouvea, 
[http://www.amazon.com/p-adic-Numbers-An-Introduction-Universitext/dp/3540629114](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540629114)